# Mitigating DB WRITE contention from concurrent messaging system

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, apache-camel, activemq-classic

**Please note:** although my question here specifically involves Camel (2.11.0) and ActiveMQ (5.8.0), its really about the proper design of a concurrent messaging solution, and could very conceivably be answered by anybody with any formidable messaging and/or concurrency experience.

I have a Camel route that starts by reading messages off of an ActiveMQ queue (`myQueue`) and sending them to a bean (`processorBean`) for processing:

```
<camelContext id="my-camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <endpoint id="myQueue" uri="myBroker01:queue:myQueue" />

    <route id="my-route">
        <from ref="myQueue" />
        <to uri="bean:processorBean?method=process" /> 
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

And:

```
public class ProcessorBean {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        String messageJSON = (String)exchange.getIn().getBody();

        // Example: now messageID might be "12345"
        String messageID = parseJSON(messageJSON, "messageID");

        // Look up DB records based on this messageID.
        // The same messageID will *always* return the same list of widgets.
        List<Widget> widgets = dao.getWidgetsByMessageID(messageID);

        // Make updates to widgets.
        for(Widget widget : widgets) {
            widget.setFizz(true);
            widget.setBuzz("Yahtzee!!!");
        }

        // Persist all updates to the widget list.
        dao.updateAll(widgets);
    }
}
```

This bean uses the message's ID (a String `messageID` field) to look up a bunch of records in a DB, make a change to them, and then saves them. It's also **very** important to note that the messages arrive at `myQueue` from an external process that I have no control over. In other words, I can't prevent messages with identical `messageID` values (hereafter "duplicates" or *duplicate messages*) from showing up on the thread. Hence this external process could send 1,000 messages onto `myQueue`, and 20 of them could all have `messageID=12345`.

Currently, I only have 1 Camel consumer configured to be running (hence it's "single threaded"). So there currently isn't any harm (besides possible unnecessary performance issues) when duplicates show up. Each message gets processed, one at a time, and if there are 20 messages with the same `messageID`, well then, the same DB records get the same exact (unnecessary) updates over and over again. Bad for performance, sure, but it doesn't create "bad data", dirty writes, our produce race conditions, etc.

I now want to add more Camel consumer threads to the equation, so that there might be, say, 10 consumer threads all reading off of `myQueue`.

Obviously, now we have a potential for WRITE contention in the DB. Say there are 2 messages on `myQueue`, and both have `messageID=12345`. One Camel consumer thread reads the 1st message, and another thread reads the 2nd message at the same time, or thereabouts. Each thread routes its message to its own copy/version of `processorBean`. Both `processorBean` instances execute around the same time, use the `messageID` to READ the same records out of the DB, performs the same operations to them in-memory, and then calls `dao.updateAll(...)` to WRITE the changes to the same records, at the same time. If both threads are updating the same DB records at the same time, there will be contention.

Another important note is that changing the DB (controlled by another team) to implement things like sharding, optimistic locking, etc., is not an option in this case (too long of a backstory).

My question: **what can be done at the Java layer to mitigate WRITE contention in this situation?** The WRITE contention *must* be dealt with from inside the application. Thoughts?

Comment: Most databases can cope with multiple writes easily.  What database are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lawrey (+1) - we're on Sybase 15....I know, I know...(again, I have no control over this). Also, for the sake of this question, let's pretend that the DB **can't** cope with multiple writes. What's a pure Java solution here?

Comment: Even so, it should be able to handle concurrent writes.  if it cannot, you can queue all your writes to one threads with a single threaded Executor, or use a global write lock in Java.

Comment: Implementing serialized writing might remove any benefit you have from multiple consumers as most of the delay will be in the database.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey (+1 on both) - any chance you could post some pseudo-code (perhaps modifying my Spring XML route and/or `ProcessorBean`) to illustrate what you mean? Thanks again!

Comment: Sybase 15 supports the `select for update` syntax. Using that you can serialize your updates without making any code changes except for the transaction that now has to span the `select` and `update`. But as was stated above, this will really make parallel consumption from your message queue a mood point. Except for higher availability, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global lock like this

```
synchronized(ProcessorBean.class) {
    // Persist all updates to the widget list.
    dao.updateAll(widgets);
}
```